# What is considered a "View" exactly?

Tags: android, terminology, android-view

Just going through the starting tutorials, and while I got the app running fine, I just want to make sure I have the Android terminology right.

For example, the first app tutorial I went through has you modify the activity_main.xml to include:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />
```

Am I correct in understanding that these (EditText, Button) elements themselves are individual Views?  In other words, the above code contains two "Views", and not two "controls"?  Later in the code we run into something called a TextView, which directly has the word "View" in it, while the others do not, which kinda threw me off.

My only other experience is in ASP.Net and C# web development, so I guess my question could be phrased as, are Android "Views" equivalent to ASP.Net Web Controls (asp:DropDownList, asp:Button, etc.)?  If I wanted to add more controls to the above code, like more Buttons for example, would I say, "I'm going to add more Views to this Layout?"  Or would it be, "I'm going to add more controls to this View?"  Or...?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: Right, that's where I went first.  It says that a TextView is a direct subclass, whereas the Button, EditText, and so on are indirect subclasses.  So is it safe to refer to the two types (direct and indirect) as "Views"?  Or should I call them "controls"? etc.

Comment: There are no "Controls" in Android world, just "Views"

Comment: @CptSupermrkt, you may see this as well : http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-controls-part-one-introduction-to-ui-in-android-and-text-controls/ There are no Controls in Android, just Views as said by fiddler

Comment: If you're ever unsure if something is a View, just look at the documentation. If it extends View, it's a View. :)

Comment: Hey all, thanks for taking the time to reply.  And thanks for the link @Habib, that's got a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A view is basically anything displayed on the screen, whether it be a button, a piece of text, a list...

Your complete layout is a view, and each item contained within it is a view as well.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <TextView/>
    <EditText/>
    <LinearLayout>
        <Button>
        <Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In the above, the RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, TextView, EditText and Buttons are all "views". LinearLayout and RelativeLayout being container views, but they can still be referenced as views in order to perform certain functions on them.

Comment: That explanation gave me that, "oh, duh, now I get it" moment where it all just makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Aren't those moments grand?  :) Happy to help.